# Code refactoring - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I think my code regarding buttons is violating the DRY principle. Can you suggest a more efficient way to reduce the clutter?

```
@IBAction func competitiveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if competitiveMatch.isEnabled == true {
        competitiveMatch.isEnabled = false
        friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
        tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
        trainingButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
    }
}


@IBAction func friendlyButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if friendlyMatch.isEnabled == true {
        friendlyMatch.isEnabled = false
        tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
        competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
        trainingButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
    }
}


@IBAction func tourneyButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if tournamentButton.isEnabled == true {
        tournamentButton.isEnabled = false
        friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
        trainingButton.isEnabled = true
        competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}


@IBAction func trainingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if trainingButton.isEnabled == true {
        trainingButton.isEnabled = false
        friendlyMatch.isEnabled = true
        tournamentButton.isEnabled = true
        competitiveMatch.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        trainingButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

The code follows a set pattern for all four buttons. I am not able to factor a shorter method to do the same. Please help. Complete beginner here.

Comment: Seems like you should be using a `UISegmentedControl` instead of 4 separate buttons

Comment: Mutually exclusive can be represented using enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `IBAction` instead of 4 separate methods. And make the sender type to `UIButton` from `Any`. Then you can do something like

```
@IBAction func toggleEnableDisable(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentValue = sender.isEnabled
    let buttonArray = [trainingButton, friendlyMatch, tournamentButton, competitiveMatch]
    buttonArray.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
    sender.isEnabled = !currentValue
}
```